# Table should be created using year month and date in SSIS?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a folder where i will get `.xlsx` file every day. I have a `SSIS` to copy the data from `.xlsx` file to a table `StackData`. But I need to create `SSIS` package such a way that when I run the package `Table` should be created with year month and date like `StachData_20130819`.

Comment: You are creating a new table with each execution or you are simply filling a column with the source file name (and date stamp)

Comment: I need to create a table with table name and current date .I will execute package every day.

Comment: Creating a table per day? That is a _bad idea_

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(10) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112); 
IF OBJECT_ID('report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_' + @d) IS NULL 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select * into report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_' + @d + ' from property.door_traffic;'; 
    PRINT @sql; 
    --EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 
END
```